# Django Login working, but Register not working

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django

I having the landing page that the user is presented with the when they navigate to the home page. This page have both the login form and the register form, the login for works as expected, however when I try to register a user nothing happens. I don't get any errors or warnings.

**views.py**

```py
def login_page(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('dashboard:dashboard')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if 'login-submit' in request.POST:
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('dashboard:dashboard')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')

        elif 'register-submit' in request.POST:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                    messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + user)

                    return redirect('dashboard:login')

    return render(request, 'main/login.html', context)
```

**login.html**

```html
<form id="register-form" action="" method="POST" role="form" style="display: none;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{form.username}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{form.email}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{form.password1}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{form.password2}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 center">
            <button type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**forms.py**

```py
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Username'}),
            'email': forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email Address'}),
            'password1': forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'password2': forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following and share the logs of your print statement?

```
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + user)

                return redirect('dashboard:login')
             else:
               print (form.is_valid())   #form contains data and errors
               print (form.errors)
```

Comment: Thank you, was my own stupidity as my test password was too common.